# How to speed up querying same table many times with different conditions?

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, optimization

EF6, asp mvc core and SQL Server are used on the background.

I have to do many queries to the same table with different conditions, f.e.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1 WHERE a = true
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1 WHERE b = true
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1 WHERE a = true || b = true
SELECT a FROM Table1 WHERE b = true
```

So 4 queries to `Table1` with different conditions. I think that as result I have to read the entire `Table1` four times. In pseudo code it might be looking like this.

```
var res1 = new list();

foreach(var rec in Table1) 
{
    // read Table1 first time
    if(rec.a == true) 
    {
        res1.push(rec);
    }
}

var res2 = new list();

foreach(var rec in Table1) 
{
    // read Table1 second time
    if(rec.b == true) 
    {
        res2.push(rec);
    }
}

var res3 = new list();

foreach(var rec in Table1) 
{
     // read Table1 third time
     if(rec.a == true || rec.b == true) 
     {
         res3.push(rec);
     }
}

var res4 = new list();

foreach(var rec in Table1) 
{ 
    // read Table1 fourth time
    if(rec.b == true) 
    {
        res4.push(rec);
    }
}
```

I want to know how to read the `Table1` only one time and get four different results, like this:

```
var res1 = new List();
var res2 = new List();
var res3 = new List();
var res4 = new list();

foreach(rec in Table1) 
{
     // read Table1 first time
     if(a == true) 
     {
        res1.push(rec);
     } 

     if(b == true) 
     {
        res2.push(rec);
     }

     if(a == true || b == true) 
     {
        res3.push(rec);
     }

     if(b == true) 
     {
        res4.push(rec);
     }  
}
```

Also the challenge, that those queries are dynamic sql, I mean that `a = true`, `b = true`, `a = true || b = true` are stored in database. And queries are running in this way:

```
string query = "SELECT Count(*) FROM Table1 WHERE" + condition;
var count = ExecuteSql(query);
```

The sample above is simplified, but in reality all the query is split and stored in database.

PS. Actually I want to speed up the page, which makes 30-40 requests to the server and each request is the query to the same table. I think if I can replace them with one request instead of 40 requests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use conditional aggregation with just a single query:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(CASE WHEN a = true THEN 1 END) AS cnt_a,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN b = true THEN 1 END) AS cnt_b,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN a = true OR b = true THEN 1 END) AS cnt_a_b
FROM Table1;
```

This would reduce the number of full table scans from 3 to just 1.  Also, it would also potentially reduce the number of round trips to/from the database from 3 to 1.

Comment: Looks very promising, I will try it.